# Is it possible to use wildcards to map urls to WSGI scripts in an apache config?

Tags: apache, mod-wsgi

I have a number of trac projects I want to have available from my webserver, is it possible to use wildcards to automatically map urls to the relevant wsgi file?

I can do it manually by adding the following virtualhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/trac.mydomain.com
  ServerName trac.mydomain.com
  WSGIScriptAlias /project1 /var/trac/project1/trac.wsgi
</VirtualHost>
```

However, as I open more trac projects the number of WSGIScriptAlias lines increases. Is it possible to use wildcards to automatically map an incoming url to the correct wsgi file? I imagine it would look something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/trac.mydomain.com
  ServerName trac.mydomain.com
  WSGIScriptAlias /<wildcard> /var/trac/<wildcard>/trac.wsgi
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typical! The google search I made after posting the question brought up a relevant result. The solution is to use WSGIScriptAliasMatch and a regular expression. Given my examples above the config would look something like this:

```
<VirtualHost 95.211.154.197>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/trac.mydomain.com
  ServerName trac.mydomain.com
  WSGIScriptAliasMatch ^[^/]+ /var/trac/$1/trac.wsgi
<VirtualHost>
```

Where ^/[^/]+ matches all characters after the root url up to the first /. E.g. http://trac.mydomain.com/matched/notmatched/notmatchedeither.whatever would map to /var/trac/matched/trac.wsgi

Comment: More specifically, it is documented on the mod_wsgi site for Trac in particular at http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/IntegrationWithTrac